# How can I ping my neighbor's Coax'd Modem?

Tags: networking, ping, isp

**Main Question**: How can I, or why can't I, directly ping/access my neighbor's PC (or even Modem) over the Coax without having an ISP? (tracert from me to him directly).

**Related (wik)**: Aren't all of the modems in my area technically a BUS Topology until they hit some node where they join the Mesh of the ISP?

**Related related (also wik)**: When my PC is sending/receiving data, aren't all of my neighbors technically getting that data too, but it is thrown out or ignored when their modems see it isn't for them? Or is my assumption wrong, and the Coax is somehow separated such that data only goes directly between me and the ISP?

I realize I could literally set up some sort of wireless meshnet or something fancy, but I just want to know how I can (or why I can't) use my Windows PC (not my Linux system) to do this.

I also realize this is only a local question, and I wouldn't be able to ping Google.com without an ISP.

Comment: You can't ping his router, because most router drop all incoming ICMP packages.

Comment: @NordlysJeger Not true at all. Reference for that?

Comment: @Fanatique For all home-routers I worked with, that was the standard configuration.

Comment: Even if so, let's assume that I may have control over my source and target (me and him) from inside if need be.

Comment: **When my PC is sending/receiving data, aren't all of my neighbors technically getting that data too** - Nope. **Or is my assumption wrong, and the Coax is somehow separated such that data only goes directly between me and the ISP?** - Yes

Comment: @Suamere , the question as asked seems like you might be trying to crack into your neighbor's equipment / data.  You might want to ask from the reverse position, like "Can my neighbor with the same cable service see my equipment or data?"  "Can't ping Google.com without an ISP" makes a reader think that you aren't paying for an ISP connection.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I considered a disclaimer to point out I'm not being malicious... but isn't that what a malicious person would say?  Lol.  Also, I had to specifically state "neighbor" to demonstrate that I am talking about people on the same node as me for sure, not some random person in another state.  Also, I see nothing wrong for not paying for an ISP connection. Circumventing the ISP's is somewhat a side-goal of my research. :D

Comment: you are not within the same node. If you're using leased line, xDSL or fiber cables then you're connecting directly to the ISP instead of some router inbetween

Answer (score 0):

Your modem is configured to connect with the host controller(Isp). Similar way your computer has your router as its host controller. 
Considering that one can setup a guest network where each guest computer on the network cannot see each other, they probably have their setup the same way.

Comment: I don't think I've _ever_ heard 'host controller' in a networking context. Mind defining it?

Comment: Your right. The term is gateway IP address

Comment: This is great information, and gives me some information that I can now research to possibly answer my own question.  But on that same note, I was hoping for a more detailed answer so my research could be streamlined as I play with this research.  So this is great, but it's more like a comment for how I can research and answer the question myself, y'know?  Which I'll definitely be doing, but that means I can't up-vote this as an answer, it seems so incomplete.